# Changing label for record counter in Survey123

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I have a survey where I am collecting nested repeating questions.  I have 3 groups; Stands, Plots, and Trees.  Stands have many Plots.  Plots have many trees.

The display of the records is a little bit confusing.  Instead of showing "1 of 1", I would like the record labels to say "Stand 1 of 1", "Plot 1 of 1" and "Tree 1 of 1".

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: If I am correct, you are using Survey 123 Connect? can you add a screenshot of the excel showing the grouped question?

Comment: You may be able to use a read-only question with a calculated answer (and a "null" esri:bindtype, so that no attribute is created to store data for it).